# How should an Android application respond to critical changes in the environment?

Tags: android

Let's say there's an application that creates an account in AccountManager. User explores the quite complicated activity graph of this application for a while, then goes to `Accounts and Sync` in Android Settings, removes the account and signs in (still being in `Accounts and Sync` as a different user.

I have defined a receiver for `LOGIN_ACCOUNTS_CHANGED` broadcast and I'm able to shut down all services gracefully. But activities are still there, bearing the name of the first user in their header (UI gets messed up in a number of ways, but this one is the most obvious).

So, the question is: what should be done about these orphan activities?

- I could use something like `clearTaskOnLaunch`, but all activities are in the background when the change happens.
- Set a flag in SharedPreferences and check in `onResume()` of each activity, then launch `clearTask` activity if needed? Too messy.
- The best option I was able to come up with is to use `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid())` to kill all activities. This is not too graceful, but gets job done. The only side effect is that activity stack is still there, when the most reasonable thing seems to be to start from the `LAUNCHER` activity, with clear history.

So, what would be the best way to respond to the described scenario?

Comment: Using Process.killProcess() is always a hack, never the correct solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have all your activities extend from a `MyActivity` class which has a `BroadcastReceiver` member: mChangeReceiver.

Have `MyActivity` register mChangeReceiver in `onCreate` (and unregister in `onDestroy`), to the `LOGIN_ACCOUNTS_CHANGED` intent.

Have the mChangeReceiver call some abstract method `onAccountChanged()` that all extending classes need to override and implement to reflect the change in the GUI.

That's it.
Now, whenever the account changes, all your living activities will get their `onAccountChanged` method called and will refresh their GUI.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, it might work. Although I was looking for a solution that would restart the application in one way or the other, because showing an activity stack of one user to the other does not seem like a good idea. I'll try calling `finish()` and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

i have some ideas based on the fact you have users-login mechanism :

about UI , how about updating the username UI (probably textview) upon onPause to "" and updating it to the current user upon onResume ?

about closing activities if needed , you can save the current user to a global variable and per activity . each activity should check if the global one is the same as the one they have stored last time they were updated . if they are different, you can close the activity . you could also use the clearTask flag as you've written.

another way to handle the activities is by using fragments stack instead . for more information check the android support examples of fragment stack.